# find matching text and replacing next line Windows 10

Tags: json, windows, text, replace, editor

I know this question was asked already, but the answer was provided for Linux.  I need to do this in Windows, either using R or Notepad++ or UltraEdit or something similar.  I need to replace the line after each instance of "see_more" in json code that is not formatted properly.

Here's an example:

```
"see_more": "/discover/categories/food?page=75&ref=category&seed=2390176"
}
{
```

I need to add a comma after the } in the middle so it looks like this:

```
"see_more": "/discover/categories/food?page=75&ref=category&seed=2390176"
},
{
```

There are thousands of these instances in these files, so it would take a very long time to do it manually.  Note that the url in the "see more" line changes.

If you need more information, please let me know.  Thank you.

EDIT:

I figured this out, sort of.  I recorded a macro (search for "see_more", move to the next line, add a comma) in TextPad and ran it to the end of the file.  Pretty easy and fast, but I doubt this would work in anything much more complex.

Comment: Is the `}` always on it's own line? Do you only want to change `}` to `},` if `"see_more":` exists? Or just any `}` that exists in the document?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I figured it out using a TextPad macro.

Answer (score 0):

In UltraEdit a **Perl** regular expression replace all can do that.

Search string:   `(?s)see_more.+?\}\K(\s*)(?=\{)`
Replace string: `,\1`

Explanation for search expression:

`(?s)` ... flag to match also newline characters with dot.

`see_more` ... this string must be found.

`.+?` ... any character (including newline characters) one or more times non-greedy.

`\}` ... the previous expression stops matching characters on finding character `}` being escaped with a backslash to be interpreted as literal character. Of course `{` should not exist in a string value as otherwise this search expression does not work as expected. But it looks like this limitation is no problem for this task.

`\K` ... resets the start location of `$0` to the current text position: in other words everything to the left of `\K` is "kept back" and does not form part of the regular expression match.

`(\s*)` ... find any whitespace character 0 or more times and mark the found whitespaces for back-referencing.

`(?=\{)` ... positive lookahead to check if next character is a left brace being escaped with a backslash to be interpreted as literal character.

The replace strings consists of the comma to insert, and back-references the whitespaces between `}` and `{` to keep them unmodified.

Another solution working most likely in all text editors with Perl compatible regular expression support including UltraEdit:

Search string:   `(see_more[\s\S]+?\})(\s*)(?=\{)`
Replace string: `$1,$2`

The dot is replaced by `[\s\S]` to match any whitespace OR any non-whitespace character which means also any character including newline characters.

The string matched from `see_more` to first found `}` is marked and back-referenced in replace string with `$1` to keep this part of found string unmodified. The whitespaces between `}` and `{` matched by `\s*` in a second marking group defined with `(` and `)` are referenced here with `$2` to keep them also on inserting the comma between.